# How to get into and add features into a cheap Bluetooth smartwatch that I bought?

Tags: bluetooth, resources, watch

I bought a cheap bluetooth smartwatch that costed like $20.

When I plug it into my computer, I cannot see the device listed. I cannot think of any other way to access the source code.

The reason I am trying to get at the source code is to add a few of my own watch faces and try to create my own features.

Any help?

Comment: I would be surprised if this was doable without taking the watch apart, but it will help to know the model of the watch (and possibly the internal chip as well)?

Comment: It is a Q7 Smartwatch with only a bluetooth (probably 4.0 or 5.0) chip and no internet chip. I’m just wondering if I could customize the display screens or change what is sent over bluetooth without having to disassemble it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `UberTooth` - it's a piece of hardware that allows you to interact with BT protocol on low level. Problem is - the device itself is like 5 times the price of your smart watch. I also don't believe you can access the source code on the watch - I believe the absolute best you'd be able to to is to get the firmware out using some unconventional method

Comment: ok thank you. ill look into that but that would be great if there was a free solution (software tool preferably) to interact with the bluetooth protocol and/or access the source code

Answer (score -1):

I guess under "plug in" you meant you've plugged it in the USB charging port. Most probably communications are disabled there by a default and the port is in charging only mode.

Try to pair it with your laptop via Bluetooth first, then try to access your watches as a bluetooth device (there is an option for the file transfer, for example, for windows see here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026874/windows-10-share-files-over-bluetooth).

Comment: How does this answer relate to the question?

Comment: Topicstarter wants to access the watches filesystem. The only interface of watches is bluetooth (and USB, but data seems disabled). WHy not to try to pair via bluetooth and check if file transfer is permitted?

Comment: Okay correct, but it's very unlikely that he will be able to access the source code of the watch via bluetooth

Comment: Uff, of course:-) But as he clarified, he'd like to change a wall paper. There are chances it's just images picked from some dir, or they are packed as resource files but accessible. That's why I suggest to pair the devices and have a look.

Comment: That's reasonable. The model of the watch is known already, maybe you can find a proven solution for changing the watchface and update your answer accordingly

Comment: Right, i have tried this already. My question was if there was a known way to access the filesystem of a cheap bluetooth smartwatch. Connecting via usb or Bluetooth obviously wont work with the charging port